# React Native Android app is getting crashed when drawer implementation is done

Tags: android, react-native

I'm actually working on single page navigation, tab navigation and Drawer navigation by using react native navigation.

After the drawer implementation is done, single page navigation is working fine but the whole application is getting crashed after clicking on a login button.

**Take a look at the code that I have written :**

**app.js:**

```js
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import AuthScreen from './src/screens/Auth/Auth';
import SharePlaceScreen from './src/screens/SharePlace/SharePlace';
import FindPlaceScreen from './src/screens/FindPlace/FindPlace';
import SideDrawer from "./src/screens/SideDrawer/SideDrawer";



// register screens

Navigation.registerComponent('example.AuthScreen', () => AuthScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent('example.SharePlaceScreen', () => SharePlaceScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent('example.FindPlaceScreen', () => FindPlaceScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent('example.SideDrawer', () => SideDrawer);


// start a app

Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
        screen:'example.AuthScreen',
        title:"Login"
    }
})
```

**startMainTab.js**

```js
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
const wDim = Dimensions.get('window');
const fixedWidth = Math.round(wDim.width * wDim.scale * 0.8);

const startTab = () =>{
    Promise.all([
        Icon.getImageSource("map",30),
        Icon.getImageSource("share",30),
        Icon.getImageSource("menu",30),

    ]).then(sources =>{
        Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
            tabs: [
                {
                    screen:"example.AuthScreen",
                    label : "Find Place",
                    title : "Find Place",
                    icon  : sources[0],
                    navigatorButtons:{
                        leftButton:[
                            {
                                icon:sources[2],
                                title:"Menu",
                                id:"sideDrawerToggle"
                            }
                        ]

                    }

                },
                {
                    screen:"example.AuthScreen",
                    label : "Share Place",
                    title : "Share Place",
                    icon  : sources[1],
                    navigatorButtons:{
                        leftButton:[
                            {
                                icon:sources[2],
                                title:"Menu",
                                id:"sideDrawerToggle"

                            }
                        ]

                    }

                }
            ],
            drawer: {
                left: {
                    screen:"example.SideDrawer"
                }
            }
        });
    })


}

export default startTab;
```

SideDrawer.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text,Dimensions,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

class SideDrawer extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View >
                <Text
                style={[styles.container,{width:Dimensions.get("window").width*0.8}]}>
                    On SideDrawer
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        paddingTop:22,
        backgroundColor:"white",
        flex:1
    }
})

export default SideDrawer;
```

sharePlace.js

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

class SharePlaceScreen extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));

    }

    onNavigatorEvent = event => {
        console.log(events)
        if(event.type === "NavBarButtonPress"){
            if(event.id === "sideDrawerToggle"){
                this.props.navigator.toggleDrawer({
                    side: 'left'
                })
            }

        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>On Share place screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default SharePlaceScreen;
```

Comment: Can you also share the error that you receive? Or is the application just closing without an error?

Comment: its closing without any error

Answer (score 1):

```
leftButton: [
    {
        icon: sources[2],
        title: "Menu",
        id: "sideDrawerToggle"
    }
]
```

This should be ,

```
leftButtons: [
    {
        icon: sources[2],
        title: "Menu",
        id: "sideDrawerToggle"
    }
]
```

Follow this link :
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/adding-buttons-to-the-navigator.
Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: thankyou, i'll check and let you know it's working or not